# Removing Dynamically added views in android crashing application on view ClickListener for removing

Tags: android, dynamic, android-view, layout-inflater

I want to implement the dynamically add and removing Views in android layout and Save the changes in shared preferences,
 Everything works fine But while i m clicking on the specific view to remove on that specific view ClickListener something went wrong and its crashing the application but its removing that view and displaying the remaining rows after i restart application

here are my codes
Any Help would be much appriciated

```
public void display_contacts()
{
    View.OnClickListener removeListener=new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
        {
            TextView removeNum=(TextView)paramAnonymousView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name1);
            if(paramAnonymousView.getId() == R.id.viewId)
            {
                mSettings.Initialize(getApplicationContext());
                mSettings.RemoveFromContactList(removeNum.getText().toString());
                mSettings.SaveSettings();
                LinearLayout displayView = (LinearLayout)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.contacts_view);
                displayView.removeView(paramAnonymousView);
                displayView.invalidate();
            }
        }
    };

    LinearLayout wrapper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contacts_view);
    LinearLayout inflatedView;
    mSettings.Initialize(getApplicationContext());
    int i=mSettings.GetContactListCount();
    if(i>0) {
    final   String[] arrayOfStrings2 = mSettings.GetContactListNumber();
    final    String[] arrayOfStrings3 = mSettings.GetContactListName();
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            String str = arrayOfStrings2[j];
            if (arrayOfStrings3[j] != null) {
                str = arrayOfStrings3[j] + "(" + arrayOfStrings2[j] + ")";
            }
            inflatedView = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.allow_deny_row, null);
            ((TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name1)).setText(str);
            inflatedView.setId(R.id.viewId);
            wrapper.addView(inflatedView);
            wrapper.invalidate();
            inflatedView.setOnClickListener(removeListener);
        }

    }

}
```

something went wrong on view and onClickListener
thanks in advance

**Update: error log**

```
01-03 15:46:33.112 17483-17483/com.example.ghaznavi.contacts D/HAWAII_EGL: Set SWAP INTERVAL 0
01-03 15:46:33.112 17483-17483/com.example.ghaznavi.contacts D/HAWAII_EGL: eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4fc82108, VC surface: 1, Thread: 17483
01-03 15:46:33.112 17483-17483/com.example.ghaznavi.contacts D/HAWAII_EGL: eglMakeCurrent(0x4fc5e2c8, 0x4fc82108, 0x4fc82108) Thread: 17483
01-03 15:46:33.122 17483-17483/com.example.ghaznavi.contacts D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-03 15:46:52.021 17483-17483/com.example.ghaznavi.contacts D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-03 15:46:52.021 17483-17483/com.example.ghaznavi.contacts W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b05960)
01-03 15:46:52.031 17483-17483/com.example.ghaznavi.contacts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at com.example.ghaznavi.contacts.Contact_main$4.onClick(Contact_main.java:132)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4380)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18094)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 15:47:10.379 17483-17483/com.example.ghaznavi.contacts I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17483 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you show the error ?

Comment: yes you can check above

Comment: Can you tell me which is the 132 line ?

Comment: LinearLayout displayView = (LinearLayout)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.contacts_view); this line in onClickListener section

Comment: Ok, i think your mActivity is null, can check it before doing this line ?

Comment: problem solved i removed mActivity from that line and it works :) thank you @RaphaelTeyssandier